# Floating point representation can support larger values in comparision to integer representation

Tags: java, javascript, c

I have googled over this,but couldn't find **how**, although it is a simple thing to answer for someone who knows it. I want to know **how** floating point can store large numbers which can't be stoed by integer representation. In the tutorials all that I could read about significand,exponent and bases but couldn't find my answer. Could anyone come up to solve it? For example,I have to represent a number larger than 2147483647 in a 32-bit system, then how it is done in floating point representation as opposed to integer representation.

Comment: I think you don't know what float (IEEE 754) actually is. Take a look at wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you assume this convention: *the last two digits* of your integer denote the power-of-10 of the remainder. Then you can store numbers up to 21474835 * 10^99 in a single integer. (You would also need to program all arithmetic methods to *use* it a such.)

To use *floating point* numbers in the same way, you can use the same convention. Since a signed integer stores 9 decimals (10, but the first one can only be 0, 1 or 2), you could say that the decimal period is behind the first decimal. So to store "1234.56" you would use

```
123456004
```

-- the decimal point convention says this is "1.23456 times 10^4", and that is the same value you stored.

Astute readers will notice that you *cannot* store 'every possible number' this way. Exceeding the maximal number of allowed decimals, for example, will have them thrown away. You can also *either* not store negative numbers *or* values smaller than 1 (please deduce why).

How is this relevant to your question? This is *exactly* how floating point numbers are stored, albeit with other conventions than I outlined. A bit is set aside to use as *sign*; a number of bits hold the "decimal" part, and another set of bits hold the "exponent" part.

Answer (score 0):

A binary floating point number is of the form s * 2^e for two integers s (significand) and e (exponent). It's actually a bit more complicated, but that doesn't matter for this question. For e=0 this is just an ordinary integer with as many bits as s has. For e > 0, this is also an integer. You can represent the number 2^40 in a binary32 float (8 bit exponent, 23 bit significand) with s = 1, e = 40. Or s = 2, e = 39. Or s = 2^23, e = 17.